# How should I give text to textbox which will displayed in textbox at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

this is my cs code

```
 int rowIndex =0;
        TextBox box1=new TextBox();
        box1.Text = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

Normally if we want to give value to textbox we give lkie this

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text="SomeText"></asp:TextBox>
```

but now I have textbox in gridview so I am accessing that as written above cs code. I want to give text to textbox from cs code. then How should I give text to textbox which will displayed in textbox at runtime..

Comment: Can you tidy up your question, so that it will be clear and can be understood.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
int rowIndex =0;
TextBox box1=new TextBox();
box1.Text = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

I think you should do this:

```
int rowIndex =0;
TextBox box1 = ((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1"));
box1.Text = "Whatever you want to display";
```

You may do this only after you bind the data to your grid.

Answer (score 0):

It will be the same way you have got the text:

```
((TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text = "SomeText";
```

But typically, the text for each row will change and folks use data-binding declarative syntax  to assign text - for example

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropertyOrColumnName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

See [data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) for quick start.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox1.text = "Some Text"
 Since U have Already Give Some ID to the TextBox Assumption 
Second U have Stated it will runat Server so it is Accessible at CS File.